# Foreach is not iterating properly /with WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, if-statement, foreach

I am trying to iterate through three recent posts and display their thumbnail, title and permalink.

The first one has a slightly different look so there is an if statement as well to display the first one in a different setting and then iterate through the rest. What is happening instead, it is showing the first post three times with styling for both if and else.

I am not sure what am I doing wrong, thanks for any help!

```
<?php
      $recent =  wp_get_recent_posts( array('numberposts' => 3) );
        $i = 0;
        global $recent_post;
        foreach( $recent as $recent_post ) {
          if ($i == 0 ): ?>
              <div class="header_recent main">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink($recent_post); ?>">
                  <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($recent_post->ID); ?>"/>
                  <div class="overlay">
                    <h1><?php the_title_attribute($recent_post); ?></h1>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
      <?php else: ?>
          <div class="header_recent side">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink($recent_post); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute($recent_post); ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($recent_post->ID); ?>"/>
                <div class="overlay">
                  <h1><?php the_title_attribute($recent_post); ?></h1>
                </div>
          </div>
    <?php endif; $i++; }
  wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Also, I would really appreciate help with the warning about `get_the_post_thumbnail` function:

> **Notice**:  Trying to get property of non-object on line
>   **29**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `wp_get_recent_posts()` returns `ARRAY` by default, as you can see in the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts). In your case you need to pass second parameter `$output` as `OBJECT`:

```
$recent =  wp_get_recent_posts( array( 'numberposts' => 3 ), OBJECT );
```

Also you shouldn't pass `$recent_post` as argument of [`the_title_attribute()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title_attribute) function. So instead of:

```
<h1><?php the_title_attribute($recent_post); ?></h1>
```

You can write:

```
<h1><?php echo $recent_post->post_title; ?></h1>
```

And you don't need to declare `$recent_post` as `global`.